# AJAX Request upon Server Offline then resumes when servers back

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, caching

Hi guys i know my questions a bit of confusion. I just like to know if this is possible or any method pertaining same concepts of
    what i want to do. ?

1. I`ll create a form field to save into mysql db through Ajax
2. Assuming the server goes down while ajax request done.
3. Ajax woudn`t return any error.
4. Instead when the servers goes up  it will continue to the pause
   request being send when the server is being offline/down

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. These are some of the things that you need to take note

1. If ajax is on failure (Ajax will return error when it can't connect to server), record the data in the browser cache. The browser should have a localstorage. Have a look at this following link to see how you can store data on the browser: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html.
2. On page load, do a constant ping to the server with JavaScript (Ajax) and see if there server is up. When the server is up, push the locally stored data to the server.

Comment: Thanks your reference is much good than what im sort of thinking. Further more im thinking of some possible cons for this not to be implement instead force the user to just redo the transaction.